# How can I query records based on User permissions?

Tags: salesforce, soql

Is there a way to only return Accounts (using SOQL) that the current user has write access to?

For example, if I go to a specific Account and click the [Sharing] button I can see a list of Users (and Groups) that have access to that record. When logged in as one of those Users, I can run a SOQL statement (through a custom Controller on a Visualforce page) to retrieve the Account record. However, I want to make sure the Account record is only returned if the User has permission to write to (or edit) that record. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to enforce sharing is to use the `with sharing` keywords. If, for whatever reason, you don't want to do this, you can wrap the DML statement in a try block at catch the `DMLException`. Call `getDmlType()` on the exception object to see if the failure was related to permission. I think the status code will be  `System.StatusCode.INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY`. Here's a somewhat complete list of [status codes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=StatusCode|statusCode#statuscode).

Comment: I am using the `with sharing` keyword, but I'm still getting records that are not writable.

Comment: Ok so they're writeable, but not readable. So I think you just have to make the DML call, then catch the exception and handle accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to know before the DML call? I don't necessarily want to update the record.

Comment: You could create a savepoint before the dml call. Then rollback if the call is successful.

Comment: That may work; it doesn't look like there's an easier way. Thanks!